# Find the kth smallest element in an unsorted array of non-negative integers

Tags: c++, algorithm

Not allowed to modify the array ( The array is read only ).
Using constant extra space is allowed.

ex: 
A : [2 1 4 3 2]
k : 3

answer : 2

I did it below way. The answer is correct but need to be more memory efficient.

```
void insert_sorted(vector<int> &B, int a,int k)
{
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        if(B[i]>=a)
        {
            for(int j=k-1;j>i;j--)
                B[j]=B[j-1];
            B[i]=a;
            return;
        }
    }
}

int Solution::kthsmallest(const vector<int> &A, int k) {

    vector <int> B;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        B.push_back(INT_MAX);
    }
    int l=A.size();

    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(B[k-1]>=A[i])
            insert_sorted(B,A[i],k);
    }

    return B[k-1];
}
```

Comment: It's trivial with `O(nk)` time. What's the time constraints?

Comment: if constraint on space complexity is more than O(n) then go for merge sort and call the kth element

Comment: What do you mean by "more memory efficient"? What is the problem with the current implementation?

Comment: @VidorVistrom another choice is calling std::nth_element

Comment: @Petar, `std::nth_element` writes through its iterators, so I don't think that's a solution (yes, it was my first thought, too).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to write up your samples in a more-complete fashion and ask for critique over at [codereview.se]. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!

Comment: @TobySpeight The reply is based on the comment "constraint on space complexity is more than O(n)", in this case we can copy the array and use nth_element on the copy

Comment: @Petar, copying the array is O(n) in space, so I don't see how that's relevant (particularly when the question says *the array is **read-only***, and only ***constant** extra space* may be used).

Comment: @TobySpeight my reply is based on the comment of  Vidor Vistrom "if constraint on space complexity is more than O(n)  then go for merge sort and call the kth element "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is binary search.

Let `A` be the input array; we want to find a number `b` such that exactly `k` items in `A` are smaller than `b`.

Obviously, `b` must be inside the range `[0, max(A)]`.
And we do binary search starting with this range.

Suppose we are searching within range `[lo, hi]`.
Let `c = (lo + hi)/2` which is the middle pivot.
There are three cases:

- number of items in `A` less than `c` are less than `k`.
  In this case the number we search for should be larger than `c`, so it should be in range `(c, hi]`
- number of items in `A` less than `c` are larger than `k`.
  Similarly, the number we search for is in range `[lo, c)`
- number of items in `A` less than `c` equals to `k`.
  In this case, the answer is the minimum element in `A` that is greater than or equals to `c`. This can be find by doing a linear search in `A` again

The complexity is `O(n log m)`, where `m` is the max element in `A`.

```
/* assume k is 0 based, i.e. 0 <= k < n */
int kth_element(const vector<int> &A, int k){
    int lo = 0, hi = *max_element(A.begin(), A.end());
    while (lo <= hi){
        int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
        int rank_lo = count_if(A.begin(), A.end(), [=](int i){ return i < mid;}); 
        int rank_hi = count_if(A.begin(), A.end(), [=](int i){ return i <= mid;});

        if (rank_lo <= k && k < rank_hi)
            return mid;

        if (k >= rank_hi)
            lo = mid + 1;
        else
            hi = mid - 1;
    }
}
```

---

Although it's not the answer to this particular problem (as it requires a modifiable collection), there is a function called `std::nth_element`, which rearranges the elements so that the *k*th element is at position `k`, and all elements at positions less than `k` are smaller than or equal to the *k*th element, where `k` is a input parameter.

Comment: @Jarod42 For the binary search solution, I did not modify the array. In each round of search, I scan through the array and count number of item less than c (current pivot).

Comment: @Jarod42 I have added my code, welcome to discuss it.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the edit!  rank_hi is the number of items less than or equals c so i think it may not equals to A.size() - rank_lo.
The reason I find rank_hi is that if there are multiple items equal to c, then there are multiple possible position of c when A is sorted. rank_lo and rank_hi are the range of possible position

Comment: Why is `lo` zero, rather than `std::min(A.begin(), A.end())`?  This method will fail if the result should be negative.  Talking of results, don't you need to return something after the `while` loop?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understood the logic but could not understand the code.

Comment: @TobySpeight for lo = 0, it is because the problem is about array of non-negative integers. Your approach is better, and I simply use 0 for convenient.  For returning things after while loop, I need to think about detail, my current idea is that the binary search will always reach the return inside the if condition.

Comment: @Chiku I think understanding the logic is more important, my code is just for illustrating the idea and could be wrong.

Comment: @Petar: I see now the constraint of *non-negative integers*.  I missed it because it wasn't mentioned in the body of the question (just the title) and the code uses a signed type - so I took that as my cue.  Sorry I didn't pay enough attention!  As for the return statement, I would either add a `return` after the loop, or change it to `while (true)` to reflect my beliefs, otherwise compiler warnings will alert me to the omission.  Perhaps you compile with more lenient settings.

Answer (score 1):

The question does not ask for any time constraints. An `O(nk)` solution is fairly simple, by iterating the array `k` times (at most), and discarding one element (and its duplicates) each time.

```
int FindKthSmallesr(const std::vector<int>& v, int k) {
  // assuming INT_MIN cannot be a value. Could be relaxed by an extra iteration.
  int last_min = INT_MIN;
  while (k > 0) {
    int current_min = INT_MAX;
    for (int x : v) {
      if (x <= last_min) continue;
      current_min = std::min(current_min, x);
    }
    last_min = current_min;
    for (int x : v) {
      if (x == current_min) k--;
    }
  }
  return last_min;
}
```

Code on ideone: http://ideone.com/RjRIkM

Answer (score 1):

If only constant extra space is allowed, we can use a simple O(n*k) algorithm.

```
int kth_smallest(const vector<int>& v, int k) {
    int curmin = -1;
    int order = -1;
    while (order < k) { // while kth element wasn't reached
        curmin = *min_element(v.begin(), v.end(), [curmin](int a, int b) {
            if (a <= curmin) return false; 
            if (b <= curmin) return true;
            return a < b;
        }); // find minimal number among not counted yet

        order += count(v.begin(), v.end(), curmin); // count all 'minimal' numbers
    }
    return curmin;
}
```

online version to play with: http://ideone.com/KNMYxA

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is correct but need to be time efficient.